# Run same async function multiple times with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I have an async function like:

```
$scope.get_device_version = function(){
       return $q(function(resolve, reject){
            $http.get('/api/get_version')
                .then(function(response) {
                    resolve(response.data.version);
                },function(response) {
                    reject("Lost connection..");
            });
       });
};
```

Question 1: Now I want to run that function 10 times in a row sequentially, what do I do?

Question 2: Now I want to run the function until I get a desired answer from the http-request, what do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

`.then(callback)` returns a new promise resolving to the return value of `callback`, or if the return value is another promise, to the settled value of that promise. This can be used to chain asynchronous calls. For example, given

```
function myFunction() { return promise; }
```

the following snippet will call `myFunction` 10 times sequentially

```
var result = $q.resolve();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    result = result.then(myFunction);
}
result.then(function () { /* myFunction has been called 10 times */ })
```

**Question 2**

Here, recursion is required since you don't know the exact number of times you will need to iterate. For example, given `myFunction` as above,

```
function wrapper() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    iter();
    function iter(res) {
        // skip first iter() call, wait for acceptable res
        if (result !== void 0 && /* res is what I want */) {
            return deferred.resolve(res);
        }

        // recurse
        return myFunction().then(iter);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}

wrapper().then(function (res) { /* res is an acceptable response */ })
```

Note that for this use case, promises do not really offer an advantage over simple callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

```
var request = null;

for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {

  if( request )
      request.then( $scope.get_device_version );
  else
      request = $scope.get_device_version();


}
```

Question 2:

```
$scope.get_device_version = function(){
       return $q(function(resolve, reject){
            $http.get('/api/get_version')
                .then(function(response) {

                    if( /*Not a desired answer? run again:*/ )
                        $scope.get_device_version()
                    else
                        resolve(response.data.version);


                },function(response) {
                    reject("Lost connection..");
            });
       });
};
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. Code-only answers seldom help.

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code, i have not tested it.

```
var checkDeviceVersion=function (times) {
    $scope.get_device_version().then(function(data) {
        if(times==0) return;
        checkDeviceVersion(times-1);
    });
}

var keepChecking=function () {
    $scope.get_device_version().then(function(data) {
        if(data.condition) return;
        keepChecking();
    });
}
```

Invoke then as `checkDeviceVersion(10)` or `keepChecking()`